# Embed SVG data in PDF

Tags: .net, pdf, svg, pdf-generation

I want to create PDF files containing SVG images. The Images should be embeded as vector graphics. Using [this project (nanopdf)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/nanopdf/) as a template, i tried to write a Programm for creating PDF files. Adding text worked, but embeding vector graphics not.

Is it possible to directly insert the SVG data into the PDF Code? Or have the SVG instructions be converted into PDF commands or something else? If this is not easily possible, I would be looking for an open source library, which can do this (preferably written in a .NET language).

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What do you mean by "don't want to render the images"?  Do you mean don't want them to be converted to embedded bitmaps? You want them to stay as vectors?

Comment: Exactly. I want the vector graphic into the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Syncfusion converter for converting SVG to PDF files.The converted PDF will contain vector graphics as per your requirement. Please check

[Working with Document Conversion](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-document-conversions#converting-svg-to-pdf)

Comment: Thank you, but as I write in my edited question now, I am looking for a way to embed the SVG data or an open source .NET library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Batik library from Apache for this https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/ or use Batik with Apache FOP for a complete solution for text and SVGs